# How to display decimals as fractions?

Tags: templating, filter

Is there a twig filter to display decimal values as fractions?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there's a plugin for that. Typography, by nystudio107.

https://nystudio107.com/docs/typogrify/#using-typogrify

===== edit =====

I was never able to get this working with typogrify. It never treated a period immediately surrounded by numbers as a decimal point.

It did inspire me to write a plugin, Fractionalize, to provide a '|fractionalize' filter which does the trick.

Comment: Do you have the Fractionalize plugin available at all. I need something like this right now : )

Comment: @JKM Please take it with a grain of salt. Let me know if it breaks anything. https://github.com/extensibleseth/fractionalize

Comment: Thanks for this. It really helped me : )